# svn update does not load all files from server

Tags: svn

From time to time I've this problem and still no clue why this happens.
Sometimes svn won't load all files with `svn up`.

Example:

```
$ svn up
Aktualisiere ».«:
Revision 18.
$ ls -alh externalFiles/
insgesamt 8,0K
drwxr-xr-x  2 me mygroup 4,0K Dez  8 10:24 .
drwxr-xr-x 10 me mygroup 4,0K Dez  8 10:24 ..
$ svn list http://svn.my-server.local/spielwiese/trunk/externalFiles/
file1.xlsx
Fahrzeugangaben-Dateien/
Fahrzeugangaben.htm
file2.docx
file3.dotx
```

As you can see there are several files inside "externalFiles" which I am missing local. I can do `svn up` as often as I want and it still won't download the missing files. I even can delete the whole directory (local of course) - `svn up` just recreates it but without files.
What happens here?

Deleting the whole repository and do a fresh new checkout can't be a real solution.

Comment: Can you show us the output of `svn info` in your working copy? I suspect that maybe you're not in the `trunk` but maybe a branch?

Comment: I double checked this and my working copy was in the right path.
But I was able to "fix" this with `svn up --set-depth infinity`
However I've no clue why I need to do this...

Comment: Could you have done a switch or something such that your working copy is not pointing at trunk?  If you do a svn info within the working copy, you can verify that you are looking at what you think you are.

Comment: my working copy definitely pointed to trunk. I know this because I checked it with `svn info` and copied the path from there to my `svn list` command.